# cocos2d test examples do not work

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The cocos2d test examples do not work they either gives me 400 erros or the debugger says 'Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.' 
How do I start the example projects that cocos2d came with?
iam running iphone simulator 4.1 and xcode 3.2.4 cocos2d for iPhone v0.99.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your issue is, but 0.99.4 is an old version of cocos2d.

I suggest using v0.99.5, it has several fixes for using retina display graphics.

Get it here: http://cocos2d-iphone.googlecode.com/files/cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5.tar.gz
API Reference: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/

Comment: thanks dude i'll let you know if the test examples start working :)

Comment: it was probably something to do with the Base SDK, in the newest version of xcode you can now set files to 'latest iOS' meaning that projects created in newer versions of xcode can be opened correctly on older versions. Or atleast, thats how i presume it works.